# Windows Files Transfer History Logs

Tags: windows, usb

Is there any way I could check the history logs of the all files copied from my windows 11 machine to an USB device and vice versa?

I tried to see the ctrl + R (regedit) I check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Windows does not record this information. So the answer is no.